# Regular Expression for KW postcodes

Tags: php, regex, drupal, drupal-7, ubercart

I'm trying to make a case insensitive regular expression for my shipping section that catches all postcodes which are in the KW section apart from KW9. I have the following regular expression which catches all KW postcodes, but how do I add an exception for KW9 to this?

```
^[kK][wW][1-9]\s?[1-9][a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I copied and pasted the wrong reg ex, here is the actual reg ex:

```
^[kK][wW][1-9]{2}\s?[1-9][a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

The valid postcodes in the KW region are KW 1-9 and KW 10-17 (but [kK][wW][1-9]{2} will validate them) and the format is (all case insensitive) kw, 1/2 digits, optional white space, a single digit and 2 letters. A valid postcode is KW1 1AA and an invalid postcode is KW9 1AA

Comment: An example of a postcode you want match and one you don't would help. But try changing `[1-9]` to `[1-8]` for the first `[1-9]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this simple one.

```
   /^KW[1-8][0-9]?\s?[1-9][A-Z]{2}$/i
```

Adding `/i` makes it case insensitive.

This matches KW1-8 and KW10-89. It does not match KW9 or KW90-99

Comment: @IgorKorkhov No It matches. I updated. But you checked the older one. :P

Comment: Thanks @Shiplu :) I used yours to make `^[kK][wW][1-8][0-9]?\s?[1-9][a-zA-Z]{2}$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(KW|Kw|kW)9\s?[1-9][a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

This should catch all KW9 case insensitive except kw9 (lowercase)

Comment: It needs to match all valid postcodes except the kw9 as that is how the ubercart shipping section accepts them as it is part of a much bigger reg ex

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/^kw([1-8]|1[0-7])\s?[1-9][a-z]{2}$/i
```

I've enabled the "case insensitive" option.
And for the 1-8 + 10-17 I've just used the (...|...) syntax. If you don't need to capture this number, you could use the "non-capturing" prefix:

```
/^kw(?:[1-8]|1[0-7])\s?[1-9][a-z]{2}$/i
```